# Tweetinvi authenticating in a universal windows 10 app

Tags: c#, authentication, oauth, xamarin, tweetinvi

I use the method Auth.SetUserCredentials(...);

When i try to authenticate in a test console app and publish a tweet everything is fine. When i do the same in a uwp app i get this error when trying to authenticate:

System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Tweetinvi.Auth' threw an exception. ---> System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
at Tweetinvi.Core.TweetinviCoreModule.Initialize()
at Tweetinvi.Injectinvi.AutofacContainer.InitializeModules()

If you want to see my code: https://github.com/matdestr/TwitterShared.git

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. I found a post that said to use the command
Install-Package tweetinviapi -version 0.9.10.2-w10-uap -pre

This stopped the error happening and now the app appears as though it should have posted, no error, but nothing is posted to Twitter.

Comment: I changed my universal app to run from localhost and it then posts OK. My problem is when I attempt to post from the RaspberryPi2 with win10 IoT.

Comment: Hello there, I have to be honest and admit that I have never tried running in W10 IOT. I will try to have a look at this but I am already pretty booked up until the release of the new version 0.9.11.0.

Comment: If you do investigate and get some promising result please keep us up to date or potentially create a pull request on github.

Cheers.

Comment: Hi, I did get this working. The issue appeared to be in the end that the Raspberry Pi did not have an up to date date and time. I rebooted it and when it picked up the correct date and time from the NTP server the software worked with no issue. Let me know if you want more detail. I was testing using an Univeral Windows App.

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue in UWP. I downgrade TweetinviApi from Nuget to version 0.9.10 and this work for me.

Comment: Have you tried the solution I provided, just above? I am confident that it will solve your problem.